# Is Induction Independent of the Other Axioms of PA?

Tags: matrices, induction, model-theory, peano-axioms

I am trying to come up with a model of first order Peano Arithmetic (PA) where induction fails. Let $PA^{-IND}$ have the same axioms as PA except the first order induction axiom schema is replaced with its negation. I need to show there exists a predicate, $P$, that makes first order induction false. $P$ must satisfy $P(0) \land \forall x(P(x) \rightarrow P(Sx))$, yet $\forall x(P(x))$ is false. We can prove multiplication is commutative using double induction on $P(x,y)= (xy=yx)$. [Why Does Induction Prove Multiplication is Commutative?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122041/why-does-induction-prove-multiplication-is-commutative)

Consider the 2x2 matrices $M_2(N)$ with the standard definitions for matrix addition and multiplication. Let the zero matrix be $0$ and the identity matrix be $S0$. $\forall x(Sx=x+S0)$ is a theorem of $PA^{-IND}$. Matrix multiplication is not commutative, yet we can prove multiplication is commutative for all the successors of $0$. Would $M_2(N)$ be a model of $PA^{-IND}$?

The negation of first order induction says there exists a predicate:
$P(0) \land \forall x(P(x) \rightarrow P(Sx)) \land Ex( Not(Px))$

This looks like quantification over predicates but it isn't. The induction schema requires us to add an infinite number of axioms to the language. The negation of induction only requires the addition of a single axiom. Unlike PA, $PA^{-IND}$ has a finite number of axioms. I have simply added a new predicate to the language.

I am using the axioms of PA given by Wikipedia for [First Order Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic). These axioms use induction to prove commutativity. Without induction, these axioms are very weak. They don't even require addition to be commutative. I would be interested in any model of $PA^{-IND}$.

Comment: What is the negation of a schema?

Comment: You are quantifying over predicates. That is not a first order quantification anymore.

Comment: I agree. We do assume the induction schema is true for all predicates. This is a quantification over predicates.

Comment: @Russell Easterly: in the Wikipedia article, $\text{PA}^-$ is the list of 15 axioms listed in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations

Comment: Thanks. I need to learn more about semi-rings. Finding a model of semi-rings where induction fails looks much harder.

Comment: I gave an example in my answer

Comment: By the way, in first order theory, you can't say $\exists P$.

Comment: Also, are you using the definition of $PA^-$ on Wikipedia, or what you defined above: Peano minus induction. Because $PA^-$ on Wikipedia takes away induction but adds in a lot of axioms that would otherwise be proved as theorems if we had induction available...

Comment: I changed the question to avoid confusion. I am using the axioms above the axioms for $PA^-$. $PA^{-IND}$ has the negation of first order induction as an axiom. The negation of induction is not first order as several people have pointed out.

Comment: @Russell Easterly: the new question is more confusing to me. You write, "a predicate, $P$, that satisfies first order induction yet ∀x(Px) is false." What does it mean for a predicate to satisfy first-order induction? It seems to me that we could take ''any'' nonstandard model and interpret the new symbol $P$ to only hold of the standard numbers in that model - that must not be what you have in mind.

Comment: @Carl Mummert: I mean a predicate that satisfies $P(0) \land \forall x(P(x) \rightarrow P(Sx))$ and also satisfies $\exists x(Not(Px))$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A structure that satisfies the axioms of Peano arithmetic except for induction is $\mathbb N[x]$, the set of all polynomials with natural number coefficients, setting the successor $S(p) = p + 1x^0$ and zero being $0x^0$.

It has a zero, successor is closed under the set, it is injective.  If you think of the Peano axioms as constraints on a directed graph, this is the natural structure to arrive at:

- $0 \in \mathbb N \land \lnot \exists x \in \mathbb N~:~ S(x) = 0$ - there is a source
- $x \in \mathbb N \implies S(x) \in \mathbb N$ - there are no sinks
- $S$ is an injective function - there are no forks in the graph

All that remains is to establish that the graph is connected, which induction does.

So you can have multiple zeros, like $\mathbb N[x]$.

Or you can have a disconnected graph, such as using $\mathbb N \cup \mathbb Z \cup \mathbb Z' \cup \mathbb Z'' \dots$ (treating each pair of the previous sets as pairwise disjoint, but otherwise maintaining their usual properties).

Or some combination of both of the above.

Answer (score 6):

You have to be careful about what you mean by $\text{PA}^-$.  The convention I expect is that $\text{PA}^-$ is the finite set of axioms for a discretely ordered semiring - which includes the axiom that multiplication is commutative. This set of axioms is typical when we want to look at systems of arithmetic with limited induction. For example, it is the set of axioms in Kaye's book *The Structure of Models of Peano Arithmetic*.

The original five axioms proposed by Peano, which only mention the successor operation, but not addition, multiplication, or order, are not sufficient for first-order Peano Arithmetic, because they are not sufficient to define addition or multiplication in first-order semantics.

On the other hand, some authors use an abbreviated set of axioms for Peano arithmetic. For example, Mendelson's logic text uses a smaller set of axioms that do not mention the order relation. These work because he only considers them in conjunction with the induction scheme. It seems to me that $M_2(\mathbb{N})$ is a model of this smaller set of axioms, but I would not call them $\text{PA}^-$.

Even when we look at the full set of axioms for $\text{PA}^-$, we can give an example of a model that does not satisfy induction. Tennenbaum's theorem shows that no nonstandard model of Peano arithmetic is computable. But the set of polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ with positive leading coefficient are a computable nonstandard model of $\text{PA}^-$, so induction must fail in that model, although I am not sure which instance of the schema fails. I believe the proof only relies on a finite number of instances of induction, so that would give a short list of candidates.

Comment: What about defining the exponential function? Might that require induction and not be possible in the structure that is the set of polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ with positive leading coefficient?

Comment: Good point - if $\alpha$ is nonstandard in that model then $\{\alpha^k : k \in \omega\}$ is cofinal, so $\alpha^\alpha$ cannot exist in the model.

Comment: A simple example to show induction fails in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Let the predicate $P(n)$ be $\exists_k : (n = 2k) \vee (n=2k+1)$. Then $P(1)$ is true, and $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$, but $P(x)$ is false.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Why is $P(x)$ false?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: because $x$ is neither odd nor even in that ring.

Answer (score 2):

If you drop the induction principle it will become easy to find a model so that the other axioms are fulfilled. Consider the set $\mathbb N\cup \{\infty\}$ where $\sigma(\infty) = \infty$ and $\sigma$ is defined as normal for $\mathbb N$. Then the other axioms are fulfilled, but the induction principle doesn't work. Consider for example the statement $\phi(x): x\in\mathbb N$. If $\phi(n)$ we clearly have $\phi(\sigma(n))$ and we have $\phi(0)$, but still $\phi(k)$ is not valid over the entire set since $\neg\phi(\infty)$ (that is the induction principle doesn't work for this set).

Comment: Isn't one of the axioms that no number is its own successor?

Comment: @NoName No, because it can be proven using the other axioms: First we have that $\sigma(0)\ne0$ by axiom. And then if $\sigma(n)\ne n$ it follows that $\sigma(\sigma(n))\ne\sigma(n)$ from injectivity of $\sigma$ and by induction we conclude that $\sigma(x)\ne x$ for all $x\in\mathbb N$

Comment: Ah, OK thanks. I had mistaken injectivity for its implication

Answer (score 1):

[Note, I'm using your definition, Peano minus induction. Carl pointed me to the wikipedia page, where $PA^-$ is defined as something quite different. There, it is Peano minus induction plus a lot of the basic theorems we normally prove by induction.]

With induction, we can prove that every natural number is either zero, or the successor of a natural number. Indeed, this is the easiest usage of induction possible. (It's my favorite induction proof, because $P(0)$ is clearly true, and $P(Sn)$ is true, whether $P(n)$ is true or not.)

There are some simple examples where the other axioms hold but this most basic induction theorem is not true.

Comment: One such example is the closure of $\omega + \omega $ under ordinal addition and ordinal multiplication.

Comment: I was think non-negative rationals, but that works too, @CarlMummert.

Comment: But I was just looking for the proof that induction was independent, not looking for specifically non-commutativity of multiplication.

Comment: $\text{PA}^-$ has the property that every model has an initial segment isomorphic to $\omega$, so $\mathbb{Q}^+$ can't be a model of that theory. It will be a model of some fragments of PA even smaller than $\text{PA}^-$, of course.

Comment: @CarlMummert which axiom is not satisfied by the non-negative rationals?

Comment: The axiom that there is no number between 0 and 1. $\text{PA}^-$ is the set of axioms for discretely ordered semirings - see my answer.

Comment: Ah, the question defines the axioms very differently as Peano without the induction hypothesis. This is something else entirely. It's really "Peano, minus induction, plus a lot of the most basic theorems we normally prove by induction." @CarlMummert

Comment: Right - Peano arithmetic includes much more than just induction and the 5 Peano axioms for successor. Even with the full induction scheme in the language with only successor, it is not possible to define addition and multiplication in first-order semantics (e.g. it is not possible to define multiplication in Presberger arithmetic).

Comment: Yes, but you can prove addition is commutative, associative, etc. So yeah, I was seeing it as "minimal Peano for addition and multiplication." Aside: Even though I've read the proof, I still don't "get" why exponentiation can be defined with a Diophantine equation. That seems mystifying to me. @CarlMummert

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So the closure of $w+w$ under ordinal multiplication and addition satisfies the axioms of PA- (as given in the link of Carl)?

Comment: Answer will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple example of PA negating induction would be the set $\mathbb N \cup C$ where $C$ is some (any) cycle in the sense that some symbol $c \in C$, and for every $x \in C$, $Sx \in C$, and $SSSSSSSx = x$.

Comment: A cycle either wouldn't have a zero or it would have a fork, defying the axiom that successor is an injective function.  Induction actually does apply to integers $\pmod p$.

Comment: @DanielV Where does this answer mention that some element of the cycle is reachable from the naturals?

Comment: @NoName You are right I must have misread it six years ago.  Maybe I took "any" too literally.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a first-order approach, but you may be able to adapt it to PA.

If we grant the existence of at least one Dedeknd-infinite set $X$, the principle of mathematical induction can be shown to be independent of the other Peano Axioms (the set-theoretic version).

Since $X$ is Dedekind-infinite, there exists a function $f: X\to X$ such that $f$ is injective and not surjective.

Since $f$ is not surjective, we have $x_0 \in X$ such that $\forall x\in X:f(x)\neq x_0$

We can construct subset $n\subset X$ such that $n=\{x_0, f(x_0), f(f(x_0)), \cdots \}$ and $(n,f,x_0)$ satisfies all the Peano axioms (PA1-5):

We can also construct a successor function $g:n\to n$ such that $(n,g,f(x_0))$ satisfies axioms PA1-4, but *not* induction.

$$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
x_0,  & \text{if $x=x_0$} \\
f(x), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

See detailed [formal proof](http://www.dcproof.com/InductionIndependent.htm).

Comment: This is a valid answer, not sure why someone downvoted it.

Comment: I have a pretty good idea.

Comment: Do you have a summary of the axiom/rules-inferences/unquanitified constants for DC-proof?  I'd be interested in reading about the logic and design choices you made in creating your software.

Comment: @DanielV I have tried without success to separately post the user manual online. You can download my software along with the manual at no cost at my website http://www.dcproof.com

Comment: I didn't downvote but probably the reason is that you didn't explain any bit of how you do the construction, and answers should be as self-contained as possible according to the rules and goals of this site. In particular, in this case everyone talking about independence knows everything you said in your post so it does not even add anything.